# IIS - SSL - How to restrict client certificate validation through intermediate CA?

Tags: ssl, iis, certificate

How to reject a client certificate, if the corresponding intermediate certificate is not registered on the server ?
Ideally, we want to check that the complete certificate chain has been registered in the issuer store.

Our attempts to use the Windows Registry entry “ClientAuthTrustMode” have proven unsuccessful.

EDIT: it looks like the registering of intermediate CA is not mandatory to validate our client's CA.

For example, if client's CA validation chain is "ClientCertificate > IntermediateCA > RootCA", and our server has only RootCA registered, then our client's certificate is accepted - and that's not what we want !

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786429(v=ws.11)

Comment: what error message did you get when you set clientauthtrustModue? Or you means it won't check the intermediate CA.

Comment: No error message ; what we observe is that, even when the intermediate CA is not installed on the machine, the client certificate is accepted, if it shares a common root with the intermediate CA.